# Why isn't 'logger.debug false' printing anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.8, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm having a problem with a boolean expression and when I did a logger.debug I had strange results, so I simplified my logging code to the following and was surprised not to see any 'false' being printed.

Logging code in my controller:

```
logger.debug 'true'
logger.debug true
logger.debug
logger.debug 'false'
logger.debug false
logger.debug
logger.debug '1 == 1'
logger.debug 1 == 1
logger.debug
logger.debug '1 == 0'
logger.debug 1 == 0
```

Which prints out the following

```
true
true

false


1 == 1
true

1 == 0
```

... ?  I would expect to see false.  When I run '1 == 0' or 'puts false' in the console I get false.  Am I missing something?

Any ideas why isn't it printing the 'false'?

ruby version: 1.8.7-p352

rails version: 2.3.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails Logger uses `||` in the code before running `.to_s`, which fails for nil and false.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/buffered_logger.rb#L65

```
def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
  return if @level > severity
  message = (message || (block && block.call) || progname).to_s ## <- this line
  # If a newline is necessary then create a new message ending with a newline.
  # Ensures that the original message is not mutated.
  message = "#{message}\n" unless message[-1] == ?\n
  buffer << message
  auto_flush
  message
end
```

You can do this instead:

```
logger.debug( false.to_s)
```

Comment: 'logger.debug (1 == 0).to_s' doesn't print anything.

Comment: How about `logger.debug((1 == 0).to_s)`?

Answer (score 2):

Logger has got a condition somewhere (`if value`), which fails for nil and false. You want `logger.debug value.inspect`.

Comment: So it should be 'logger.debug (false).inspect'  ?  Do I understand you correctly?  Because that also prints nothing.

Comment: Never mind.  'logger.debug false.inspect' works fine.  The parentheses were there for expressions.  Thanks +1

Comment: For future reference 'logger.debug( (1 == 0).inspect)' works.